# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, cors

I'm using ember.js and it is throwing me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:20000/accounts/0. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

On my server side, I have placed codes to print out a log for GET, POST and PUT calls. It does NOT print out anything. Therefore, I think the client-side never made any requests to the server. (However, access 'http://127.0.0.1:20000/accounts/0' manually does indeed invoked the log on the GET method.)

The server-side is already coded to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and it works for other methods.

**So, what is my problem?**

And just for for the record, the server side in Java is:

```
responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, auth-token");
responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
responseBuilder.allow("OPTIONS");
```

and in my ember.js config/environment.js I have:

```
ENV['contentSecurityPolicy'] = {
        'default-src': "*"
    };
```

Comment: preflight means an `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: allow OPTIONs request also

Comment: Do the ports match? Different port = different domain so http://localhost:4200 isn't the same domain as http://127.0.0.1:20000

Comment: well the error states that localhost:4200 is denied ... so this should allow it, once OPTIONS is allowed as well

Comment: After debugging, I found out that the error above is caused by Chrome making an HTTP OPTIONS request to the server. I added the logging code on the server side and confirmed it. I'm still trying to resolve this entire problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
private static void setAccessControlAllowOrigin(ServletContextHandler context) {
        FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(CrossOriginFilter.class);
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "http://127.0.0.1:4200");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,PUT,HEAD");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
        holder.setName("cross-origin");
        FilterMapping fm = new FilterMapping();
        fm.setFilterName("cross-origin");
        fm.setPathSpec("*");
        context.getServletHandler().addFilter(holder, fm);
    }
```